# Откуда взять график курса биткоина за месяц?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Откуда взять данные (xml или json) ежедневного изменения курса биткоина и других криптовалют?  Нужно получить график типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: 1. получить откуда-то данные. 2 построить по ним график. С чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: если конкретнее, нужна информация, где можно найти данные (xml или json) ежедневного изменения курса биткоина и других криптовалют, по типу такого, только тут изменения доллара: https://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1=10/01/2023&date_req2=26/01/2023&VAL_NM_RQ=R01235

Comment: вы перепутали этот сайт с поисковиком?

Answer (score 0):

`Yahoo finance`, данные за последний месяц:

```py
# pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BTC_Ticker = yf.Ticker("BTC-USD")
BTC_Data = BTC_Ticker.history(period="1mo")
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
sns.lineplot(data=BTC_Data[['High', 'Low']])
#plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.title("BTC-USD")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]